# How to read more than 23 byte on Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know there is a limitation of 23 bytes in Android BLE.

There are several stackoverflow questions about **sending** more than 20 bytes.

But my question is, how to **read** more than 20 bytes with Android BLE.

Yes, it can be easily done with manipulating MTU, but Kitkat does not support **requestMTU** you know :(

With naive implementation,

```
override fun onCharacteristicRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
    new String(characteristic?.value)
}
```

this only produce first 23 bytes.

Comment: Two options. Either your counterpart BLE device requests a higher MTU or you have to split your data into several messages (segmentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904341/requesting-mtu-with-bluetooth-low-energy-connection-on-android-4-3-4-4-api-18-2).

Although if you do have control over the peripheral, you might want to chunk your data.